# Haproxy redirect https from different domains to just one without having ssl cert for each

Tags: ssl, redirect, haproxy

I'm looking for a way to redirect ssl traffic from one domain to another, without having a ssl cert for all of them with HAproxy.
Redirecting from http to https is working fine so far.

like this:

https://a.com -> https://a.org

https://b.net -> https://a.org

there is only one ssl cert for a.org.

any ideas are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect to https, you must have ssl cert for the destinition sites. Forexample you must have ssl cer on a.com, b.net, a.org.

After you have ssl cert on all sites you can simple redirect all traffic by modifying the .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```